# How to install Xuggler?

Tags: java, apache, maven, video, netbeans

I am trying to install Xuggler. In order to install those, I should first download them. So, I went to their download page.http://www.xuggle.com/downloads

There is no download link to download the .jar files. But some Maven stuff. Is that mean, I have to download it using Maven? Sorry to ask this question but I have no idea about maven. If the answer is yes, please be kind enough to guide me step by step, from creating the maven project to installing xuggler. For more information, I am using netbeans, but got eclipse too.

Please help

Comment: Take another look at the download page. You can download and use it without maven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The downloads can be found here: http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/

It's a bit hidden in their download page, look for "Using Xuggler WITHOUT Apache Maven or Apache Ivy". Also, I join their recommendation - learn Maven and see what it can do to your project.

Comment: I Marked your answer as the answer, but it is not working 100%. It only provides jar's which are not enough. You have too go here

http://gregoire.org/2010/08/25/building-the-latest-xuggler-for-windows/

Comment: xuggler sucks...they are not telling correctly how to install and set it up...for a begineer its a bit frustrating to do that....

Comment: @YaseiNoUmi Link is broken

Answer (score 2):

I had a hard time finding the installer as well and suddenly this link popped up.

Seems like someone picked up the slack and continues to host the installer file.

The development of Xuggler was annouced to be stopped in 2011 (or so) - and since then the existing documentation went downhill (like missing videos in the "how-to" sections).

Working installer for Windows 7 64 bit:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/xuggler-users/_CENGtVgMwQ